# Woocommerce operation based on attribute

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-theming

I want to make an operation in the product summary section for a value in product attributes. For example, if there is a "white" "color" among the attributes of the product, a custom text is written in the product summary section. It should do this control from product attributes, **not variations**.
With another explanation;
Check the "color" attributes of the product and if "white" value is available, write custom text in the product summary section.

EX:
The code block below performs transactions by product category. I want this process to be performed if the product attribute is "white".

```html
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'dosmtg' );
function dosmtg() {
    $text .= 'Do something';    
if( has_term( array('catagory_of_product', 'add_catagory'), 'product_cat' ) ) { //catagory
        echo $text; 
     }  
}
```

Comment: Please provide us with more details. Do you have any screenshot of some sort? Do you have any script to start with?

Comment: The question is edited..